# SQLITE DataBase,No such colum found in table

Tags: android, sqlite

Guys Can u please help me to solve this.. After Spending many time i Could not find the error.

Here is my Code

```
    public static final String DATABASENAME = "IdeaCellularDatabase";

// Table Name
public static final String AUDIT_TABLE = "audit_table";
public static final String IMAGE_TABLE = "images_table";

// Column Name
public static final String HOARDING_ID = "_hoardingid";
public static final String AUDIT_DATE = "_auditdate";
public static final String STATE = "_state";
public static final String DISTRICT = "_district";
public static final String LATITUDE = "_latitude";
public static final String LONGITUDE = "_longitude";
public static final String CELLID_LOCATIONID = "_celllocid";
public static final String CREATED_DATE = "_createddate";
public static final String IMAGEFILENAME = "_imagefilename";
public static final String IMAGEURI = "_imageuri";

// Table Create Statements
// Audit table create statement
public static final String CREATE_AUDITDATAABLE = "create table "
        + AUDIT_TABLE + " (" + HOARDING_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + AUDIT_DATE + " DATETIME " + STATE + " text, " + DISTRICT
        + " text, " + LATITUDE + " real, " + LONGITUDE + " real, "
        + CELLID_LOCATIONID + " text, " + CREATED_DATE + " DATETIME "
        + ");";
public void insertCustomerData(HoardingDetail datalist) {
    openToWrite();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // int size = datalist.size();
        db.delete(AUDIT_TABLE, "1", null);
        values.put(HOARDING_ID, datalist.getHoardingId());
        values.put(AUDIT_DATE, datalist.getAuditDate());
        values.put(STATE, datalist.getState());
        values.put(DISTRICT, datalist.getDistrict());
        values.put(LATITUDE, datalist.getLatitiude());
        values.put(LONGITUDE, datalist.getLongitude());
        values.put(CELLID_LOCATIONID, datalist.getCellId_cellLocation());
        values.put(CREATED_DATE, datalist.getCreatedDate());

        long t = db.insert(AUDIT_TABLE, null, values);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } finally {

        close();
    }

}
```

After All this I am getting Error like this..

table audit_table has no column named _state

Error inserting _latitude=878 _state=Rajasthan _hoardingid=235 _createddate=2014-02-12 09:45:09 _auditdate=2014-02-12 09:45:09 _longitude=768 _district=Buldana _celllocid=
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table audit_table has no column named _state (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO

audit_table(_latitude,_state,_hoardingid,_createddate,_auditdate,_longitude,_district,_celllocid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Please Help me...
Thanks,

Comment: Missing comma after `AUDIT_DATE + " DATETIME` in your query

Comment: and Why you add this `db.delete(AUDIT_TABLE, "1", null);` into  `insertCustomerData()`?

Comment: That would be under comment...sorry....

Comment: try to uninstall your app and install again and create this database table

Comment: or if u still get this error then post u r other code also.might be error generated some where else?

Comment: Okay.. I made mistake when i was inserting my table in db..I put wrong table name...Thanks to you.. :)

Comment: do not forget to accept or +1 up

Answer (score 0):

You are missing comma in your table create statement. Instead of

```
+ AUDIT_DATE + " DATETIME " + STATE + " text,
```

use

```
+ AUDIT_DATE + " DATETIME, " + STATE + " text,
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
"create table "
    + AUDIT_TABLE + " (" + HOARDING_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
    + AUDIT_DATE + " DATETIME " + STATE + " text, " + DISTRICT
    + " text, " + LATITUDE + " real, " + LONGITUDE + " real, "
    + CELLID_LOCATIONID + " text, " + CREATED_DATE + " DATETIME "
    + ");";
```

With

```
 "create table "
    + AUDIT_TABLE + " (" + HOARDING_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
    + AUDIT_DATE + " DATETIME, " + STATE + " text, " + DISTRICT
    + " text, " + LATITUDE + " real, " + LONGITUDE + " real, "
    + CELLID_LOCATIONID + " text, " + CREATED_DATE + " DATETIME "
    + ");";
```

You just missing comma after **AUDIT_DATE + " DATETIME,"** in your query

Comment: Thanks for your help..but it still exists.. :(